# CSS sliding div on button click

Tags: html, css, angular2-mdl

I have designed a div more less like floating action buttons: on a button click a strip slides from left to right but I can not style it properly with my knowledge of css.

```
 <div class="progress  mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet">
  <button style="float: left;" mdl-button mdl-button-type="mini-fab" (click)="toggleSliding()">
    <mdl-icon>check_circle</mdl-icon>
  </button>
  <div *ngIf="showProgress" class="progress-sliding">TEST</div>
</div>
```

And my current css:

```
.progress{
    height: 5vh;
}
.progress-sliding{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    height: 6vh;
    display: -webkit-box;
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;

    left: -1500px;
    -webkit-animation: slide 0.6s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation: slide 0.6s forwards;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% { left: 0; }
}
```

There are couple of issues:

1. I have fixed the right border radius but it looks ugly on left side
   [image]
2. The div slides from behind the screen on left which looks ugly and how can I make it slide from smoothly from the FAB button itself?

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/fhFoEqbiXt2cEVQOzzJP?p=preview

Comment: can you please post code snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: apply 'position:absolute' for .progress-sliding class

Comment: All the code that I have is above i.e. HTML and CSS apart from that I have just a .ts file (It's angular component) which I guess is not relevant here..

Comment: Check this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/fhFoEqbiXt2cEVQOzzJP?p=preview